# Upload "Snapshot" Functionality

Tags: feature-request

I find that picture(s) often enhance a post, but it is quite tedious to create/upload pictures for my posts. This is especially true when multiple pictures are required.

On my end, the normal process would be to use print screen/a clipping tool, crop, save as file, and then upload. I now have one/many files saved, cluttering up my computer, and have wasted time at each step.

Numerous other programs have an "upload snapshot" function, where you can select a area of your screen, and it uploads directly. Is this something Stack Exchange could implement?

As this post would be incomplete without a picture, here's an example from (ironically) imgur showing multiple image upload:

[image]

Comment: Way too much work IMO. You can paste an image from memory by CTRL+V in Chrome browser.

Comment: This seems pretty unnecessary to me. Most sites don't have much of a use for screenshots, so in most cases it would be interface clutter for no gain. Plus, the UI your screenshot illustrates probably uses a Windows API, which a website like Stack Exchange would not be able to hook into. Websites are pretty strictly sandboxed, and it's unlikely that they would have any way of seeing the rest of your screen.

Comment: I agree with the comments. It's a good idea given the amount of screenshots we all use, but there are already many 3rd party tools, and even just 2 buttons - screenshot then Ctrl-V in some cases.

Comment: While not perfect, if you are a windows user, consider Snipping Tool.  It will reduce a couple of your steps.  And while it likely isn't feasible to implement here, I don't think your question is as bad as others feel.

Answer (score 2):

You're doing it wrong.

If you're using a snipping-type tool to take screenshots, all you need to do is *copy the image to the clipboard* and, after you click the picture icon, *paste it using **ctrl-v***.

This saves you the intermediate step of saving the image to the desktop.

Pasting an image into the upload dialog only works if the data in the clipboard is an image. So, for example, you can't copy and paste an image *file* from the desktop, but you could copy a portion of the image in an editor and paste *that*.

Here's a picture of one of our mods (I won't say whom) that I opened in paint.net, selected a portion of his/her portrait, ctrl-c'd it, then came here to ctrl-v into the **Add Image** dialog.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think the inclusion of pictures is important but that this functionality is unnecessary when weighed against what it would take to implement.

I always save screenshots from Snipping Tool, etc to a file called Capture.png in my Pictures file. By overwriting it no build up of old screenshots occurs.

If I want to include two or three screenshots for a particular question or answer then I just save them as Capture2.png, Capture3.png, etc using the same principle.